# jQuery can't access input field in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change an input field value from dynamically loaded HTML.  However, I can't seem to find the right code.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$.get('/js/dynamic/locations', function(newRow) {
    var existing_elem = $('.edit-table tr:last').after(newRow); 
    var appendedRow = $('table tr:last-of-type');
    appendedRow.find('td[data-th="Name"] > span').text(v.location_name);
    appendedRow.find('td[data-th="Name"] > input').val(v.location_name);
});
```

The span text is updating correctly, however the input value is not updating at all.

Here is the value of newRow:

```
<tr>
  <td data-th="Name">
    <span class="edit-input-text"></span>
    <input class="inp input-edit" type="text" name="location_name" value="">
  </td>
  <td data-th="Address"><span class="edit-input-text"></span>
    <input class="inp input-edit" type="text" name="address" value="">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: How do you know that input is not updated? (attribute is not going to change if you are looking in dev tools).

Comment: Because I am viewing the source in Firebug.  The span gets updated but the input value does not.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console? Where is `v` defined?

Comment: There are no errors in console and v is defined above.  I know v.location_name exists because this line works `appendedRow.find('td[data-th="Name"] > span').text(v.location_name);`

Comment: The source wont update when you use `val()`. The source in firebug shows original source unless you use `attr('value')`

Comment: @ShaunakD This is what I thought, however OP has type=text input, so the change in value should have beed refected in UI too.

Comment: To clarify: *"however the input value is not updating at all."* it's not updated in Firebug or it's not updated on the screen too? How do you check it?

Comment: I'm checking it via Firebug.  As I said before the `span` gets updated when I view in Firebug so I can't see why the input value shouldn't get updated?

Comment: Tell us exactly which version of jquerry you are using, this changed between versions. -add it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your HTML structure and code I can tell for *sure* that it's fine and input value is indeed updated.

The reason for confusion you have lays in the difference between properties and attributes. They are not the same. How do you test that input value has changed?

> Because I am viewing the source in Firebug. The span gets updated but the input value does not.

You need to upderstand that since you are updating input with `val` method - you are setting input value property, not attribute. Attributes is not going to change unless you update it directly with `setAttribute` method (`attr` in jQuery).

Comment: I managed to get it working by changing val() to `attr('value', v.location_name)` - thanks